# Linux CVS Access Control

Tags: cvs, access-control

What is the best approach to implement access control on CVS repositories hosted on a Linux server? The goal is to prevent accidental deletion of modules by developers. The developers should be able to do all other CVS activities.

Comment: I don't know what kind of constraints you're under, but note that if you're using subversion instead of CVS, you can prevent deletions, etc, by adding an appropriate pre-commit hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CVSACL is a patch for CVS. It adds two new subcommands (acl & racl) to cvs for access control list management.

http://cvsacl.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Use SSH access: [howto cvs-ssh](http://forrest.apache.org/docs_0_70/howto/cvs-ssh/howto-cvs-ssh.html), [other howto](http://www.seul.org/sys/doc/dev-faq/ssh-cvs-FAQ.html)

It also looks like you're trying to give them a shell? And access to a CVS repository filesystem? If yes, then it isn't necessary. They do not need access to repo filesystem to do all standard CVS activities.

Answer (score 0):

mount ro? No but seriously, if you prevent module deletion, there is still nothing preventing them from deleting the content of the module, so I don't really understand the question. What should they be able to do precisely?